# Program runs every line at once

Tags: c++

I'm a bit new to programming and am having trouble figuring out why the entire code runs at once. How do I make it so it asks the user one thing at a time?  I'm sure it's something very simple but I must have forgotten it.  Thanks.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{

    int length;  
    int width;
    int height;
    int numberCoats;
    int squareFeet;
    int name;
    int paintNeeded;
    int brushesNeeded;
    int coatsPaint;
    int gallonsPaint;

    cout << "Welcome to the program! What is your first name? \n";
    cin >> name;


    cout << name << " What is the length of the house?";
    cin >> length;


    cout << name << " What is the width of the house?";
    cin >> width;


    cout << name << " What is the height of the house?";
    cin >> height;

    cout << name << " How many coats of paint will it need?";
    cin >> coatsPaint;


    squareFeet = length * width * height;
    paintNeeded = squareFeet / 325;
    brushesNeeded = squareFeet / 1100;
    gallonsPaint = coatsPaint * paintNeeded;

    cout << name << " , the amount of square feet is " << squareFeet << endl;
    cout << name << " , the amount of coats of paint you will need is " << coatsPaint << endl;
    cout << name << " , you will need " << gallonsPaint << " of paint" << endl;
    cout << name << " , you will need " << brushesNeeded << " of brushes" << endl;

                    system("pause");
                    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `name` is an `int`. That doesn't sound right. Are you entering a string for `name`?

Comment: ah good catch, you are correct I'll fix that right away

Comment: Also if you use string you need `#include <string>` in your header

Comment: Ugh I hate it when I forget basic things like this, thanks for catching that.

Comment: Chad, just a couple of housekeeping points: 1) it's not a good idea to change a question into a fundamentally different one, especially one that no longer has the problem :-) ; and 2) the correct thing to do once your problem is solved is to upvote all those answers that you consider useful and accept the best, not just put a comment in the question that it's solved.

Comment: I'm a little confused by point #1, what did I change the question to, do you mean the getline comment?                                                                   I did upvote your answer but it said since I have < 15 reputation score it wouldn't show so I edited the post saying it's solved so more people wouldn't bother trying to solve a problem that's already solved but if that's not proper ettique I'll be sure to stop.

Comment: Chad, I was referring to revision 2 of the question where `name` was changed from `int` to `string`, effectively removing the problem and rendering the question obsolete. The other edit wasn't really that important, I was just stating how you generally reward anyone that helps you out. And yes, it takes 15 rep to vote up but you can always accept answers to the questions you ask (this has the added advantage of upping your own rep a little as well). This can be done by clicking on the outline green tick mark next to the answer you want to accept.

Comment: Ah I did not know of that green tick mark, thank you, I will be sure to use it from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enter (for example) `Chad` as your name, the `cin >> name` will *fail* because `name` is an integral type, not a string type.

That means that `Chad` will be left in the input stream and all the other `cin >> xx` statements will fail as well (as they are also integral types).

If you were to enter your name as `7`, you'll find it works just fine, other than the fact that's not your name :-)

A better solution is to change `name` into a `std::string` and use `getline()` to read it in:

```
#include <string>

std::string name;

getline(cin, name);
```

The reason to use `getline()` rather then `cin >>` is because the latter will stop on white space whereas the former will get the whole line.

In other words, entering `Chad Morgan` will still have the problem you're currently seeing since it will accept `Chad` as your name and attempt to get `Morgan` as youer house length.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.  I really appreciate it.  The program works like a charm now.  The getline makes sense, I'll start using that and maybe it will cover up stupid mistakes like this :).

Comment: @Chad, have expanded on the reason for preferring `getline(cin, somestring)` over `cin >> somestring`.

Comment: Thanks for expanding on it.